# Use a different dto depending on whether a value is received or not

Tags: nestjs

I have a route that allows either to connect a merchandise to a product, or to create the product.

If we receive merchandiseProductId, we connect the product to the merchandise.
Otherwise we create the product.

The problem is that I have to put the fields required to create my product as optional, because if we pass merchandiseProductId then we don't create the product, we just connect it.

I would like that if I receive merchandiseProductId then I pass in the connectMechandiseProduct DTO, but if I don't receive it, I pass in createMerchandiseProduct.

Or, in my DTO, if I don't have merchandiseProductId then the Product fields are required, otherwise they are optional.

Thank you in advance for your help.